# PHP and Javascript value passing

Tags: javascript, php, html, geolocation

I'm using Html5 geolocation to get the coordinates of the user and sending them via Javascript to an external PHP file to reverse geo-locate the adress:

```
xhr.open( 'GET', 'utility/fetch.php?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng, true );
```

On **fetch.php** I'm reversing geo-locating the street adress and whatever I need parsing the response and sending it back.

```
function geo_callback(r){
    var result = //parsing r and getting required data
    /*
     some code here for declaring variables and stuff
    */
    //printing the result from database 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
    }
    //sending result to another external php to fetch data from database
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "utility/coord_to_add.php?result="+result ,true);
    xmlhttp.send(); 
}
```

Now my question is, is this an efficient way to do this? Let's ignore all the error handling I am just providing the method I'm using here. Plus, I realized that the data I get back as result and print it inside the "result" `div` does not apply the CSS.

Comment: Yes. About all there is to say

Comment: You might want the PHP to output JSON though, will make it easier to add more information too in the future and is also easy for JavaScript to process.

Comment: but the weird thing is, the css is not applying, lets say that I echo the result from database as : 
    echo "<div class='customDIV'>".$someData."</div>";
no css is applied although the .customDIV exists

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient (in terms of network resource & time) to use some kind of MVC framework, and add the information you are adding to the db during the call to `"utility/coord_to_add.php?result="+result` as part of the call to `'utility/fetch.php?lat='+lat+'&lng='+lng` instead. If you are providing more data as part of your

```
/*
 some code here for declaring variables and stuff
*/
```

section (manipulating the var `result`), then I'd suggest you provide all the data to a single endpoint, rather than using the multi-stage approach you have used here.